# android eclipse graphical layout is really small size

Tags: android, android-layout

android eclipse graphical layout is really small size, it was normal in first activity but when I tried to open new activity from first activity the size of graphical layout has changed,I have tried to fix it .here is what look like:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2agtdmr.jpg

Comment: You have the wrong dropdown selected for your device, notice it says Android Wear Round. Just select a device that is a phone or tablet from the dropdown and it will be fixed

Comment: @inner_class7 thank you for the comment, but please can you explain it more? I have tried many device nexus one>google> I tried all of them.

Comment: yes, when you view the top bar while looking at your xml layout you can see the device selected is Android Wear Round, as per your screen shot. if you are able to see this dropdown select it and switch to a phone for your layout to show correctly

Comment: @inner_class7 thank you so much, I have tried all of them but it did not work.

Comment: dear @inner_class7 how can I accept your answer, thanks a lot ,finally it worked.